# SSIS project Target Server Version changing unexpecteldy

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, ssis, version

We have SSIS project with Target version

[image]

We need to use this target version if someone need to load some data or for develop packages. We are using VS 2017 with latest patches. If someone try to change some package of project and deploy  only this package into SSISDB then next opening of project in VS will show that now target server version 2019. All developers use VS 2017 only (double checked this). Why target version changing to 2019 ? We can't run this with target version 2019 because few times saw such problems like not full loading of data despite on green mark check after package completion and this happenig only with target version 2019 , everything is good when we changing target version back to 2017 and running the same packages. But this is difficult to control everyone to change target server version back to 2017 every time when someone just need to make some minor changes to some of package of the project.

Here are versions of our services

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22-GDR) (KB4583457) - 14.0.3370.1 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 18:19:52   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Integration Services 14.0

Visual Studio Proffessional 2017 15.9.46

Just step by step what i'm doing :

Open my project in Visual Studio 2017 and check target server version

[image]

It is not comfortable for us due to strange behavior of Visual Studio when loading some data

Then im changing Target Server Version and Visual Studio Starts to modify every of my packages inside this project ( to translate this to English it says "converting of packages in progress" )

[image]

Now project has target version 2017 ( and per picture above every package got some changes due this target version changing ) I deploy this back to SSISDB

I open this project again in visual studio ( load from SSISDB everything that i deployed earlier ) and see

[image]

Then I open any of packages and just do minor changing inside , save this to current opened project in VS ( target server version still 2017 )

Then I deploy package to SSISDB (exacly package not project ) and i'm sure that this package was made with target version 2017.

Then I open my project again from SSISDB and now I see

[image]

Comment: *Someone* is changing it; simple as that.

Comment: Or , perhaps, you have changed your selected configuration, as the TargetServerVersion is saved alongside that (which is useful, as it means that I can deploy 2019 packages to our Dev and UAT server, and older versions to our production, as it's not gone through the upgrade yet).

Comment: No one changed this. If I open project with target version 2017 in VS , open some package and just move some task  to make sure that I made some changes , then I  save  this changes to project ,then I deploy this into SSISDB. When again i open this project in Visual studio i see that target server version is 2019. I know where i can see history of package changes inside SSISDB and completely sure that there were no changes except mine.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to see such a change in the SSISDB; you cannot deploy a package designed for SQL Server 2019 to a 2017 instance. Also, when you change the project's setting you are saving the project, right? (That is **not** the same as saving the package.)

Comment: Yes , when i change target server version I deploy whole project. But per my understanding this will change version every package inside this project. Unfortunately looks like this does not work such way , i dont see if i can change version fro separate package only. So how to handle this problem ? For example if i open some package and run some dataflow which should load one million row then this load 500K rows and show me green check mark. When I open and run same package with target 2017 this will load 1 milion rows as expected.

Comment: I didn't ask if you deployed the project. Save <> Deploy.

Comment: *"So how to handle this problem ?"* I don't; I have *never* seen this problem since the TargetServerVersion feature was introduced in 2015/2016 (I can't remember which year specifically), and I have used SSIS extensively over those years, nor have i heard any of anyone else having this problem (and I'm confident I would have seen it it in at least one of the communities I use if it were a real problem).

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a configuration set to SQL Server 2017 and a configuration set to SQL Server 2019.

You need to ensure that you're selecting a configuration of 'All Configurations' when you set the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2017.

[image]